# Setfecl: Option -m incomplete, why?

Tags: command-line, permissions, acl

My commands:

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

It returns:

```
setfecl: Option -m incomplete
```

I was trying to google this issue, but I found nothing.

Comment: You should separate multiply `-m` arguments with a comma (`,`) not another `-m`. I don't think that's your issue though.

Comment: You sure you are having this issue? I just ran the same commands as you did, and gave me no error.

Answer (score 0):

Those commands are correct as they are.

You can get the respective error only if you have a space character inside ACL spec (in your case `u:www-data:rwx` or `` u:`whoami`:rwx ``). An wrong example:

```
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data :rwx -m u: `whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
#                             ↑          ↑
```

So, please check again more carefully!